# Ceiling insulation where there are no soffit or ridge vents

Tags: insulation, ceiling, roof, vent

I want to insulate the ceiling in my garage, but it has no soffit vents or ridge vents. (Currently it is completely uninsulated and there is a vent in the attic space to the outside to maintain the roof temp.) Roof is slate if that makes a difference.

From what I read the real only options are add vents, or closed cell spray foam. I don't want to do either of those options.

Are there any other options?

In the picture you can see the slope of the back of the roof, and at the top is where the attic starts:

[image: the slope of the back of the roof, and at the top is where the attic starts]

Comment: This is a rather open-ended question, and since you haven't explained _why_ you don't want to go with the common solutions, we can't very well suggest other solutions with any confidence.

Comment: I don't understand this remark, can you elaborate? "there is a vent in the attic space to the outside to maintain the roof temp."

Comment: I dont want to do the common solutions due to cost. Both options would be quite expensive.

I mean there is a vent on the wall of the attic area that allows the attic spaces to "Vent, but its not a ridge or soffit vent. (just googled, I guess it would be a gable vent) And If I chose to insulate the roof the vent would become pointless to keep open.

Comment: Section 806 of the IRC forbids enclosed rafter spaces unless there's "cross ventilation" of every rafter space--basically a soffit vent at one end and a ridge vent or ventilation continuity with a soffit vent at the other end. I would categorize spray foam as enclosed and therefore requiring soffit vents at least. Anything beyond kraft paper vapor barrier should probably be considered enclosed. I'm not sure how to categorize kraft paper.

Comment: Is putting insulation *atop* the roof deck an option? Also, what are ground snow loads like where you're at?